# How to make calculations on hexadecimal numbers with awk?

Tags: awk, hex

I have a file containing a list of hexadecimal numbers, as `0x12345678` one per line.

I want to make a calculation on them. For this, I thought of using `awk`. But if printing an hexadecimal number with `awk` is easy with the `printf` function, I haven't find a way to interpret the hexadecimal input other than as text (or `0`, conversion to integer stops on the `x`).

```
awk '{ print $1; }'                     // 0x12345678
awk '{ printf("%x\n", $1)}'             // 0
awk '{ printf("%x\n", $1+1)}'           // 1                 // DarkDust answer
awk '{ printf("%s: %x\n", $1, $1)}'     // 0x12345678: 0
```

Is it possible to print, e.g. the value +1?

```
awk '{ printf(%x\n", ??????)}'          // 0x12345679
```

*Edit*: One liners on other languages welcomed! (if reasonable length ;-) )

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the original `nawk` and `mawk` implementations the hexadecimal (and octal) numbers are recognised. `gawk` (which I guess you are using) has the feature/bug of not doing this. It has a command line switch to get the behaviour you want: `--non-decimal-data`.

```
echo 0x12345678 | mawk '{ printf "%s: %x\n", $1, $1 }'
0x12345678: 12345678

echo 0x12345678 | gawk '{ printf "%s: %x\n", $1, $1 }'
0x12345678: 0

echo 0x12345678 | gawk --non-decimal-data '{ printf "%s: %x\n", $1, $1 }'
0x12345678: 12345678
```

Comment: However, it seems that mawk is restricted to 32 bits numbers:  
```$ echo 0xa12345678 | mawk '{ printf "%s: %x\n", $1, $1 }'  

0xa12345678: 7fffffff```

Comment: if u want it re-print it to hex, yes, it's limited to signed 32-bit ints, but just for reading in, it can read it a LOT more, even at reduced precision :
 echo 0xFACEBEACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFFACEEFFFACEFACFACEEACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACEBEFACEEFFFACEFACFACECFAD | mawk '{ printf("%.3f-bits :: %.f\n",log($0)/log(2),$0) }'      
1007.970-bits :: 26874249890840347008951537650970489156010462996064997379117454191627840106815525889891……...

Comment: i just tested it …. straight up reading is limited to 2^1024 cap of IEEE 754 double-precision format.  it can also substring the input properly, so u can parse it section by section if you have a high-precision library/function that can give u an exact value.

Comment: for the same input to work without calling other functions in gawk, either -n (non-decimal input) or posix mode -P (capital P, -p is pretty print). those or strtonum( ) are still double-precision float format limited. GMP is needed to get exact. even if the 0x prefix isn't present in the input, one can prepend  ( please see my response at bottom at this page for better formatting)

Comment: The manual recommends not to use [`--non-decimal-data`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data.html): *This option may disappear in a future version of gawk.*

Answer (score 14):

gawk has the `strtonum` function:

```
% echo 0x12345678 | gawk '{ printf "%s: %x - %x\n", $1, $1, strtonum($1) }'
0x12345678: 0 - 12345678
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you don't need *awk* at all, as string/number conversion is hairy. *Bash* versions 3 and 4 are very powerful. It is often simpler, clearer and more portable to stay in *Bash*, and maybe use *grep* and *cut* etc.

For example, in *Bash* hexadecimal numbers are converted naturally:

```sh
$ printf "%d" 0xDeadBeef
3735928559
$ x='0xE'; printf "%d %d %d" $x "$x" $((x + 1))
14 14 15
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

here are the different combinations of their behaviors :

using this command

```
'BEGIN { print 0xFACECAFEFEED^2, -0xFEEDCAFEFACEBEEFDEADFACEFEED7,
 -"0xCAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFECAFE" }'
```

gawk -e (GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1))

```
  76046928626116243263483543552 -82729151009071240233065844435845120 0
```

gawk -P -e

```
  00 0
  -21377898657284658184582485743897013874545437686817998522919218577408
```

gawk -c -e

```
  00 0 0
```

gawk -n -e

```
  76046928626116243263483543552 -82729151009071240233065844435845120
  -21377898657284658184582485743897013874545437686817998522919218577408
```

gawk -S -e

```
  76046928626116243263483543552 -82729151009071240233065844435845120 0
```

gawk -M

> `760469286261162451570298`**`16169`**
>  `-827291510090712390075005672609`**`50231`** 0

gawk -l mpfr

```
  76046928626116243263483543552 -82729151009071240233065844435845120 0
```

nawk (macos awk version 20200816)

```
 00 0 -2.13778986572846581845824857439e+67
```

mawk 1.3.4

```
 00 0 -2.13779e+67
```

mawk2-beta (1.9.9.6)

```
 00 0 0
```

In fact, if one has a custom awk-script library that works across multiple awk variants, but also wanna take their idiosyncrasies into account, one approach would be use the difference in outputs here to auto-flag, with relatively few combinations left where one needs a tie-breaker.

Answer (score 0):

*** this is *only* an extension of my comment following schot's response, strictly for proper formatting purposes.

```
echo FACEBEACEBEFACEEFFFACEEEFFFACEFACFACEB | 
    mawk '{ printf("%s\n%.f\n%x\n%.f\n",$0,$0,"0x"$0,"0x"$0) }'

FACEBEACEBEFACEEFFFACEEEFFFACEFACFACEB
0
ffffffff
5593196314036579851314282024549245003233230848

5593196314036579608368524797845507287542639851 #exact
```