# hexadecimal literals in awk patterns

Tags: macos, unix, awk

awk is capable of parsing fields as hexadecimal numbers:

```
$ echo "0x14" | awk '{print $1+1}'
21 <-- correct, since 0x14 == 20
```

However, it does not seem to handle actions with hexadecimal literals:

```
$ echo "0x14" | awk '$1+1<=21 {print $1+1}' | wc -l
1 <-- correct
$ echo "0x14" | awk '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}' | wc -l
0 <-- incorrect.  awk is not properly handling the 0x15 here
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683110/how-to-make-calculations-on-hexadecimal-numbers-with-awk

Comment: @RobertoNavarro its a different question entirely.  I'm asking about using hexadecimal literals directly in the awk command (as shown in the third awk command)

Comment: I've been trying different variations, you can laugh at this if you want, but thought I'd post it before I hit go to bed: bash$ hex=20; echo $((16#$hex+1)) | echo '0x'`awk '{printf "%x\n", $1;}'`

Comment: @RobertoNavarro I'm surprised you didn't suggest the simpler `awk '$1+1<='$((0x15))'{print $1+1}'`, which is actually pretty clever (and if you make that an answer I'll give you an upvote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're dealing with two similar but distinct issues here, non-decimal data in `awk` input, and non-decimal literals in your `awk` program.

See [the POSIX-1.2004 awk specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_17), *Lexical Conventions*:

```
8. The token NUMBER shall represent a numeric constant. Its form and numeric value [...]
   with the following exceptions:
    a. An integer constant cannot begin with 0x or include the hexadecimal digits 'a', [...]
```

So awk (presumably you're using `nawk` or `mawk`) behaves "correctly". `gawk` (since version 3.1) supports non-decimal (octal and hex) literal numbers by default, though using the `--posix` switch turns that off, as expected.

The normal workaround in cases like this is to use the defined *numeric string* behaviour, where a numeric string is to effectively be parsed as the C standard `atof()` or [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strtod.html) function, that supports `0x`-prefixed numbers:

```
$ echo "0x14" | nawk '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}'
<no output>
$ echo "0x14" | nawk '$1+1<=("0x15"+0) {print $1+1}'
21
```

The problem here is that that isn't quite correct, as [POSIX-1.2004 also states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_02):

```
A string value shall be considered a numeric string if it comes from one of the following: 
   1. Field variables
   ...
and after all the following conversions have been applied, the resulting string would 
lexically be recognized as a NUMBER token as described by the lexical conventions in Grammar
```

UPDATE: `gawk` aims for "2008 POSIX.1003.1", note however since the 2008 edition (see the [IEEE Std 1003.1 2013 edition `awk` here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)) allows `strtod()` and implementation-dependent behaviour that does not require the number to conform to the lexical conventions. This should (implicitly) support `INF` and `NAN` too. The text in *Lexical Conventions* is similarly amended to optionally allow hexadecimal constants with `0x` prefixes.

This won't behave (given the lexical constraint on numbers) quite as hoped in `gawk`:

```
$ echo "0x14" | gawk  '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}'
1
```

(note the "wrong" numeric answer, which would have been hidden by `|wc -l`)
unless you use `--non-decimal-data` too:

```
$ echo "0x14" | gawk --non-decimal-data '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}'
21
```

See also:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html

This accepted answer to this [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614775/converting-hex-to-decimal-in-awk-or-sed) has a portability workaround.

The options for having the two types of support for non-decimal numbers are:

- use only `gawk`,  without `--posix` and with `--non-numeric-data`
- implement a wrapper function to perform hex-to-decimal, and use this both with your literals and on input data

If you search for "awk dec2hex" you can find many instances of the latter, a passable one is here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1352504 . If you want something like gawk's `strtonum()`, you can get a portable awk-only version [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strtonum-Function.html).

Comment: very informative!  turns out the `("0x15"+0)` works here.  Does it also work in gawk (without -n)

Comment: Without any options, no: for conversion it's treated as "0" followed by non-decimal junk, hence numerically 0. If you use `--posix` then it works, which is slightly odd. What's odder still is that `-n` also makes it work. This is possibly one of gawk/awk/POSIX's dustier corners. (For bonus points: there's a bug in gawk-3.0.4 which gets the divisors all wrong, when converting "0x15" to decimal it results in 1.3125 (i.e. 21/16)...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you stuck with an old `awk` version? I don't know of a way to do mathematics with hexadecimal numbers with it (you will have to wait for better answers :-). I can contribute with an option of `Gawk`:

> -n, --non-decimal-data: Recognize octal and hexadecimal values in input data.  Use this option with great caution!

So, either

```
echo "0x14" | awk -n '$1+1<=21 {print $1+1}'
```

and

```
echo "0x14" | awk -n '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}'
```

return

```
21
```

Comment: I'm not using gnu awk, and unfortunately that `-n` option is not available, but what confuses me is that my version clearly parses hex literals in the input data (as shown by the first command `echo "0x14" | awk '{print $1+1}'`).

Comment: @Nirk: However that command doesn't work for my version (**GNU Awk 4.1.0**). It returns `1`. I only know of that workaround with `gawk`. Sorry.

Comment: Now that's really interesting.  I'd expect the gnu version to do the "right thing".  Nonetheless, I learned something from this, so have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever awk you're using seems to be broken, or non-POSIX at least:

```
$ echo '0x14' | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{print $1+1}'
1
$ echo '0x14' | nawk '{print $1+1}'
1
$ echo '0x14' | gawk '{print $1+1}'
1
$ echo '0x14' | gawk --posix '{print $1+1}'
1
```

Get GNU awk and use strtonum() everywhere you could have a hex number:

```
$ echo '0x14' | gawk '{print strtonum($1)+1}'
21
$ echo '0x14' | gawk 'strtonum($1)+1<=21{print strtonum($1)+1}'              
21
$ echo '0x14' | gawk 'strtonum($1)+1<=strtonum(0x15){print strtonum($1)+1}'
21
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question.  `$ echo "0x14" | awk '{print $1+1}'` works just fine.  The issue came when using a hexadecimal literal in the pattern (like in the third case -- if hexadecimal literals worked properly, then `$ echo "0x14" | awk '$1+1<=0x15 {print $1+1}' | wc -l` would be 1, not 0)

Comment: I did read the question and the point is that `echo "0x14" | awk '{print $1+1}'` does NOT "work" with your awk. It produces the output YOU expect/want but that is not the correct output. All other awks, including the 2 different POSIX awks I tested, produce the same output as each other and are consistent in their handling of a hex numeric string within themselves (it's a string, not a number). Producing the output one person thinks it should produce does not mean it works, especially when it only behaves as you expected in SOME cases.

Comment: @SheetJS This is because the initial question is worded a little bit confusingly as well...(at least IMO) I too had to read it twice to figure out what the OP was actually on about. I even hacked in the lines here locally to learn which output *was* expected and which wasn't. "Clarity" would've been something else by my definition ;)