# Compare two txt files containing Hex numbers

Tags: sed, awk, text-processing

I have two files A.txt and B.txt containing Hex values. A.txt looks like:

```
blah blah blah ;AA=0012FF34, BB=0012FC0
blah blah blah ;AA=00120F54
blah blah blah ;CC=00978E4A
blah blah blah ;AA=007649A4, BB=0032FFF, CC=00F5FC6
```

and B.txt is something like:

```
b-base    b-size
00020000 00001000 blah blah blah
00030000 00001000 blah blah blah
00040000 00001000 blah blah blah
000E0000 00001000 blah blah blah
000F0000 00005000 blah blah blah
```

How can I print the lines of A.txt in which the value of AA, BB, CC, or DD in that line is inside one of the following boundaries:

```
00020000< <00020000+00001000
00030000< <00030000+00001000
00040000< <00040000+00001000
000E0000< <000E0000+00001000
000F0000< <000F0000+00005000
```

Point: The first part of A.txt (before ";") can have any arbitrary length.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Anything you're stuck with in particular?

Comment: This is too complicated a problem for sed, and too painful a problem for awk as it has no straightforward way of doing hexadecimal math.  Start by attempting this in your favorite "proper" scripting language such as Python, Ruby or Perl.

Comment: Not true of awk I think... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683110/how-to-make-calculations-on-hexadecimal-numbers-with-awk

Comment: Very well, I stand corrected.  Seems to depend awfully strongly on one's awk implementation though.

Comment: What is your expected output? Format?

Comment: The comments and answers likes to place a competition for awk guru. really interesting. But normally I don't support to provide any solutions, when OP only waits for the answer.

Comment: @BMW I agree - so I shut up and I provided an awk answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some Perl that should do the job, as it seemed like a bit much to do in AWK or sed. It constructs a hash of the ranges in `B.txt` and prints out any lines from `A.txt`, where any one of the values in the comma separated list lies within any of the ranges (currently `>=` start and `<` end). Note that this was a bit of a learning exercise for me, so I welcome any constructive feedback.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh,"<","B.txt" or die "couldn't open file: $!";
<$fh>; # skip first line
my @range;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @F = split;
    push @range, [hex($F[0]), hex($F[0]) + hex($F[1])];
}
close $fh;

open $fh,"<","A.txt" or die "couldn't open file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    my $match = 0;
  OUTER:
    for (split ',', (split ';')[1]) {
        chomp (my $val = (split '=')[1]);
        $val = hex $val;
        for my $ref (@range) {
            if ($val >= $$ref[0] && $val < $$ref[1]) {
                $match = 1;
                last OUTER;
            }
        }
    }
    print if $match;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Stunned no-one else did it in awk!!! What's going on?

```
gawk '
   BEGIN {j=0}
   FNR==NR {
      lo[j] = strtonum("0x"$1)
      hi[j] = strtonum("0x"$2)+lo[j]
      j++
      next
   }
   {
      line=$0                 # Save line in case we need to print it
      sub(/.*;/,"",$0)        # Remove everything before semicolon
      split($0,a,",")         # Split rest on commas into array a[]
      for(x in a){            # Iterate through all AA=, BB=, CC=
        sub(/.*=/,"",a[x])    # Remove everything up to and including = sign
        d=strtonum("0x"a[x])  # Convert to decimal
        for(y in lo){
           if((d>=lo[y])&&(d<=hi[y])){print line;break}
        }
      }
   }
   ' B.txt A.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I also felt this was beyond the scope of awk and sed, so I did the same as Thomas, but in python. Feel free to use this or improve on it any way you see fit.

```
def main(a, b):
    with open(b) as bf:
        data = bf.readlines()[1:]
        limits = get_limits(data)
    with open(a) as af:
        for line in af:
            maybe_print(line, limits)

def get_limits(data):
    limits = []
    for line in data:
        base, size = line.split(' ')[0:2]
        limits.append((int(base, 16), int(size, 16)))
    return limits

def maybe_print(line, limits):
    data = line.split(';')[1]
    data = data.split(', ')
    for datum in data:
        value = int(datum.split('=')[1], 16)
        for base, size in limits:
            if value > base and value < base + size:
                print line,
                return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

I run it like this: `python <scriptname> A.txt B.txt`

Answer (score 1):

My Ruby implementation, for the record...

```
ranges = File.readlines("B.txt").grep(/^([\dA-F]+)\s+([\dA-F]+)/i){ ($1.hex)..($1.hex+$2.hex) }
File.open("A.txt") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
        numbers = line.scan(/\b\w+=([\dA-F]+)/).collect{|x| x.first.hex }
        puts line if numbers.detect{|x| ranges.detect{|y| y === x } }}
    end
end
```