# Unwanted zeros in AWK output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, terminal, cut

### Problem explanation

Using `bash` on Ubuntu, I read some data packets continuously over the serial (it's connected to a wireless base-station) using a *java prog* and pipe it through `cut` and `awk` to get a result. I use `unbuffer` to see the output in real-time (otherwise the output waits till the buffer is full).

Syntax of the command that I issue on the terminal:

```
java prog | unbuffer -p process1 | unbuffer -p process2
```

Actual command I issue:

```
java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb |
unbuffer -p cut -c49-50,52-53,55-56,58-59,60,61-62,64-65,67-68,70-71,72,73-74,76-77,79-80,82-83 |
unbuffer -p awk -F " " '{printf("%d %5.4f %5.4f\n",("0x"$1)*1,("0x"$2)*2*0.0005714,("0x"$3)/612500)}'
```

My output:

```
43301 1.9370 5.0124
0 0.0000 0.0000
43303 1.9279 5.0071
0 0.0000 0.0000
43305 1.9428 5.0125
0 0.0000 0.0000
43306 1.9428 5.0072
0 0.0000 0.0000
. 
.
.
```

Line of zeros aren't real but spurious. If I execute only the *java prog* (i.e., before `cut`) or *java prog + process1* (i.e., before `AWK`), they don't appear. They appear in the output only after *process2*, after using `awk`.

### What I want

I wanna find out why the zeros are there in my output and how.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

---

### Supplementary data

One of the received data packets looks like this (output after *java prog*). All are `hex` (ungrouped at this stage):

```
 00 FF FF 00 01 1C 22 95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 83 00 00 06 95 00 2E BF 60 00 2E C0 BB 00 00 00 00
```

Above, it looks like all numbers are in groups of two. But there are number clusters within -- hence why I `cut` them in such a way that I regroup them accordingly. Output after `cut` is as follows:

Output after *java prog + process1*:

```
0000A995 00000697 002EBE00
0000A998 0000069F 002EE4FB
0000A99C 000006A4 002EBF9F
0000B421 000006A4 002ECC6B
 .
 .
 .
```

NOTE: The two outputs are not their own conversions. They were taken at different instances, just to provide an example only.

Comment: Trailing spaces on the output lines — ick.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I checked. There aren't any trailing spaces on the output lines.

Comment: Then please show your actual code because `"%d \n"` forces a space before the newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I answer my question inspired by the answer I got + the great comments and help tidbits.

## Problem

Using `awk`. No `gawk` installed.

Command:

```
 java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb |
 unbuffer -p cut -c49-50,52-53,55-56,58-59,60,61-62,64-65,67-68,70-71,72,73-74,76-77,79-80,82-83|
 unbuffer -p awk -F " " '{printf("%d\t%5.4f\t%5.4f\t\n","0x"$1,("0x"$2)*2*0.0005714,("0x"$3)/612500)}'
```

Output:

```
 2723   1.9233  5.0164  
 0  0.0000  0.0000  
 2726   1.9268  5.0164  
 0  0.0000  0.0000  
 2730   1.9428  5.0073  
 0  0.0000  0.0000  
 2732   1.9348  4.9866  
 0  0.0000  0.0000
 .
 .
 .
```

Zeros were undesirable.

## Solution

Installed `gawk`. Using it, I changed the command as in the following:

Command:

```
 java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb |
 unbuffer -p cut -c49-50,52-53,55-56,58-59,60,61-62,64-65,67-68,70-71,72,73-74,76-77,79-80,82-83|
 gawk -F " " --non-decimal-data '{printf("%d\t%5.4f\t%5.4f\t\n","0x"$1,("0x"$2)*2*0.0005714,("0x"$3)/612500)}'
```

Output:

```
 2723   1.9233  5.0164  
 2726   1.9268  5.0164  
 2730   1.9428  5.0073  
 2732   1.9348  4.9866  
 .
 .
 .
```

Zeros gone. Only changes were `gawk` instead of `awk`, addition of `--non-decimal-data` option, and removal of `unbuffer -p`.

*Note: When I leave `unbuffer -p` on, the zeros reappear. Food for thought. Perhaps, someone can attend to that later.*

Comment: Great! So it was a matter of `awk` / `gawk` and how it handled digits.

Comment: @fedorqui I suspect it was also about `unbuffer`, too. When I added another pipe (to write the output to a file) to my solution above, the zeros restarted! So, fed up with `unbuffer`, I used `stdbuf -oL` at the beginning of every process (to do line buffering) except the first one. All works fine now. I'm unable to explain the problem in detail without any in-depth knowledge of how `unbuffer` and `pipe` works. The _core_ problem remains a mystery, but the _superficial_ problem is resolved :) Thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `printf("%d \n","0x"$1)`, that is `printf` expecting a digit to be the value of `Ox$1`. Hence, when it is not a digit, `awk` prints a `0`.

Probably you want to use `%s` instead, so that a string will be printed.

See an example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf("%d \n","0xAA")}'
0 
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf("%s \n","0xAA")}'
0xAA
```

You can see a full list of Format control letters of printf in the awk manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters.

Interesting reading related to hexadecimal values in awk and gawk: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_77.html

Comment: Thanks. I perform some calculations other than the simple MWE I showed. So, the real command looks like this actually `java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb | unbuffer -p cut -c49-50,52-53,55-56,58-59,60,61-62,64-65,67-68,70-71,72,73-74,76-77,79-80,82-83 | unbuffer -p awk -F " " '{printf("%d %5.4f %5.4f\n",("0x"$1)*1,("0x"$2)*2*0.0005714,("0x"$3)/612500)}'`. The `%s` doesn't work. I tried it, too. No luck there.

Comment: @mlomailom but note you are using `%d` for `"0x"$1`. Is this the one you changed?

Comment: +1 yes this `printf` format appears to be the problem.

Comment: @fedorqui no, that's the command I used earlier before posting this question. I use `"0x"$1` 'cos I want the hex numbers to be decimal to perform calculations on (like in the other 2 columns). `%s` on `"0x"$1` doesn't work either -- I tried.

Comment: @mlomailom then it would be interesting to see how each number is mapped to the output. I guess `0000236B` maps to `9192` and so on, but I don't see the logic clear enough. It would be good if you can provide a clear sample of the input before `cut` and before `awk`, because it really looks that `printf` is having some troubles with the data.

Comment: @mlomailom: Am I missing something?  I tried numerous variations on `awk 'BEGIN { d = 0xAA; printf("%d\n", d); }'` and cannot get `awk` to recognize hex constants, much to my surprise.  It treats it as 0 each time.  This is on a Mac with the BSD `awk`. _[…time passes…]_ When I tried it with `gawk` (GNU `awk`), it worked as I expected immediately.  So, could the version of `awk` you're using be at issue?

Comment: @fedorqui they aren't exact same outputs and their conversions. Just samples. @JonathanLeffler My `AWK` version is `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996` Lemme add an edit to the problem to clarify further.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is interesting that `awk 'BEGIN { printf("%d\n", 0xAA); }'` prints `170` to me, whereas `awk 'BEGIN { printf("%d\n", "0xAA"); }'` prints `0` in my `GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0`. I am wondering if the `""` are forcing `awk` to consider it as a string, hence the impossibility to print as digit. Also, note the OP addressed a comment to you.

Comment: @mlomailom what if you try `printf("%d \n", 0x$1)`, that is, without `""` around `0x`?

Comment: @fedorqui tried it. I get `0`. I edited the problem to reflect the actual problem I have. Yep, `"0x"` attaches the `0x` bit to the hex numbers (given by `$1,$2,$3`) that aren't there after _process1_. I need that, as otherwise I can't perform calculations on them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your example: `awk 'BEGIN { d = 0xAA; printf("%d\n", d); }'`. My output is `0`. I tried `awk 'BEGIN { d = AA; printf("%d\n", "0x"d); }'`...also `0`. Then I tried `awk 'BEGIN { d = "AA"; printf("%d\n", "0x"d); }'`...output is `170`. So, I think the `cut` passes on `strings`. In _process2_ (in `AWK`) the `" "` concatenates `0x` on to them, as you can see in the variation of your example.

Comment: @mlomailom: `awk` switches between strings and numbers rather easily.  The '`d = "AA"; printf("%d\n", "0x"d);` code works with BSD `awk`, producing 170.  You may need to use `$1""` to convert `$1` into a string; you can often use `$1+0` to convert it into a number.  I think you've got the bits you need to resolve your problem, but I've not integrated them into a unified answer.  I wasn't aware that BSD `awk` doesn't support hex constants; I learned something.  Sometime, I'll need to check the POSIX spec to see if it is just a bug (it feels like it should be).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there is an interesting answer on this: [How to make calculations on hexadecimal numbers with awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3683206/1983854)

Comment: I installed `gawk`. Then my output was all `0`! I changed my command to this: `java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb | unbuffer -p cut -c49-50,52-53,55-56,58-59,60,61-62,64-65,67-68,70-71,72,73-74,76-77,79-80,82-83 | gawk -F " " --non-decimal-data '{printf("%d\t%5.4f\t%5.4f\t\n","0x"$1,("0x"$2)*2*0.0005714,("0x"$3)/612500)}'`. Only changes are `gawk` instead of `awk` and `--non-decimal-data`. Then my desired output reappeared and the zeros vanished. Thanks @JonathanLeffler. Thanks @fedorqui for the last comment and link!